# Unable to build a node js image in openshift cluster version 4.10

Tags: node.js, docker, openshift

I have a dockerfile for node, we are unable to build the image with the error

> Expecting to build an image with latest node version when done a s2i from github to openshift in Openshift cluster v4.10

We have tried this with all the versions possible of node combinations but didn't help.

Pasting the error logs for you reference

```
npm ERR! code EBADENGINE
npm ERR! engine Unsupported engine
npm ERR! engine Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.1.0
npm ERR! notsup Not compatible with your version of node/npm: npm@10.1.0
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || \>=20.5.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v16.18.1"}
npm timing npm Completed in 313ms

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /opt/app-root/src/.npm/\_logs/2023-09-25T09_05_43_269Z-debug-0.log
npm timing command:run Completed in 884ms
npm notice
npm notice New major version of npm available! 8.19.2 -\> 10.1.0
npm notice Changelog: <https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v10.1.0>
npm notice Run `npm install -g npm@10.1.0` to update!
npm notice
npm timing npm Completed in 953ms
```

Comment: Hi there, please also share Dockerfile~

Answer (score -1):

```
npm ERR! notsup Required: {"node":"^18.17.0 || \>=20.5.0"}
npm ERR! notsup Actual:   {"npm":"8.19.2","node":"v16.18.1"}
```

The error message you're encountering indicates that the version of Node.js (and npm) installed in your Docker container does not match the version expected by your project's dependencies. Specifically, your project requires Node.js version ^18.17.0 || >=20.5.0, but the installed Node.js version is v16.18.1.

Update your Dockerfile to use a Node.js version that matches the project's requirements. You can do this by changing the FROM statement in your Dockerfile to specify a Node.js

```
FROM node:20.5.0
```